# Wrong audience for id_token in IdentityServer4

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I'm trying to setup a solution with the following:
 - IdentityServer4 instance
 - React / js client
 - ASP.NET Core API (protected by IdentityServer)

Since I want to use roles and claims, I would like to use a reference token (`id_token`) and have the API verify the claims against the IdentityServer.

[image: Reference token flow]

Configuration for the **IdentityServer** instance:

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "IdentityResources": [
      "openid",
      "email",
      "phone",
      "profile"
    ],
    "ApiResources": [
      {
        "Name": "b2a6f5a1-9317-4b2f-bb02-c2f7cd70ce9a",
        "DisplayName": "My API",
        "ApiSecrets": [ { "Value": "<BASE 64 ENCODED SHA256 HASH OF SECRET>" } ]
      }
    ],
    "Clients": [
      {
        "Enabled": true,
        "ClientId": "976d5079-f190-41a2-a6f6-be92470bacc0",
        "ClientName": "My JS client",
        "ClientUri": "http://localhost:3000",
        "LogoUri": "logo.png",
        "RequireClientSecret": false,
        "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": true,
        "RequireConsent": false,
        "ClientClaimsPrefix": null,
        "AccessTokenType": "reference",
        "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "implicit" ],
        "RedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:3000/authentication/login-callback" ],
        "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:3000/authentication/logout-callback" ],
        "AllowedCorsOrigins": [ "http://localhost:3000" ],
        "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "email", "phone", "profile", "b2a6f5a1-9317-4b2f-bb02-c2f7cd70ce9a" ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Configuration for the (protected) **API**:

```
  "Identity": {
    "Authority": "https://localhost:44311",
    "ApiName": "b2a6f5a1-9317-4b2f-bb02-c2f7cd70ce9a",
    "ApiSecret": "<UNHASHED SECRET>"
  }
```

**Startup.cs** for the API:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Identity:Authority");
        options.ApiName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Identity:ApiName");
        options.ApiSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Identity:ApiSecret");
    });
```

I query IdentityServer for an *id_token* with the following parameters:

```
export const Settings: any = {
    authority: "https://localhost:44311",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/authentication/logout-callback",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/authentication/login-callback",
    response_type: "id_token",
    scope: "openid email profile phone b2a6f5a1-9317-4b2f-bb02-c2f7cd70ce9a"
};
```

I get the following error: `Requests for id_token response type only must not include resource scopes`.

If I change the scope to:

```
export const Settings: any = {
    // ...
    scope: "openid email profile phone" // removed (protected) api resource
};
```

it works and I get an `id_token` like this:

```
{
  "nbf": 1573798909,
  "exp": 1573799209,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44311",
  "aud": "976d5079-f190-41a2-a6f6-be92470bacc0",
  "nonce": "d768a177af684324b30ba73116a0ae79",
  "iat": 1573798909,
  "s_hash": "HbWErYNKpgsiOIO82IiReA",
  "sid": "vVWVhLnVLiCMdLSBWnVUQA",
  "sub": "90f84a26-f756-4923-9d26-6104eef031ac",
  "auth_time": 1573798909,
  "idp": "local",
  "preferred_username": "noreply",
  "name": "noreply",
  "email": "noreply@example.com",
  "email_verified": false,
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

Note that the audience is `976d5079-f190-41a2-a6f6-be92470bacc0`, which is the js client.
When I use this token on the protected API, it says:

```
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience '976d5079-f190-41a2-a6f6-be92470bacc0' is invalid"
```

which is not that strange since the API has the id `b2a6f5a1-9317-4b2f-bb02-c2f7cd70ce9a`.

So my question is: Where am I wrong? How do I get the token for the correct audience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ID token` will be validated by your client app (React/js) app to get user claims , so the audience is your client app's client ID . A token passe to your web api should be validated by web api , so the audience is web api's name  .

The `ID token` contains information about an End-User which is not used to access protected resource , while `Access token` allows access to certain defined server resources .You can set `response_type` to `id_token token` , and add api name/scope to `scope` configuration . With implicit flow , after authentication , client will get one  `ID token` and one `Access token` , you can now use access token to access the protected web api .

Comment: Thanks. This is basically what I could figure out as well. My first understanding was that I could use my `id_token` all the way, but this seems to be the correct way of doing this.